# In Swift NSAttributedString has more characters than String?

Tags: string, swift, nsattributedstring

I am trying to add attributes to some ranges in Swift String.
I found ranges of first and last symbol in substring and color the text between them (including) in red.

```
let mutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
let str = mutableString.string
//Red symbols
var t = 0
let symbols = mutableString.string.characters.count
while t < symbols {
    if str[t] == "[" {
    let startIndex = t
    while str[t] != "]" {
        t += 1
    }
    t += 1
    let endIndex = t

    mutableString.addAttribute(
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName,                    
        value: UIColor.redColor(),   
        range: NSMakeRange(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex))
    }
    t += 1
}
```

But I found that ranges in String and in NSMutableAttributedString are not equal. Range in String is shorter (this text is not in Unicode encoding). 
Is there a some way to find ranges not in underlying String but in NSAttributedString to find it correctly?

Example:

```
print(mutableString.length) //550
print(mutableString.string.characters.count) //548
```

Why is this difference?

Comment: "this text is not in Unicode encoding" What does _that_ mean?

Comment: It is Windows CP1251 encoding

Comment: "It is Windows CP1251 encoding" Well, no it isn't. A String is Unicode. You should have converted from Windows CP1251 when you created the string. What you have now may be something of a mess.

Comment: Thank you so much. Different length is because of "\r\n" symbol !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distinguish between String and NSString, even though they are bridged to one another. String is native Swift, and you define a range in terms of String character index. NSString is Cocoa (Foundation), and you define a range in terms of NSRange.

Comment: Thank you. I found similar question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832930/swift-string-count-vs-nsstring-length-not-equal

Comment: And see my online book, at this section: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#SBmismatch

Comment: A great book! Thank you, Matt !

Comment: The "similar question" is a good link, it saved me on
```performValidatedReplacement(in: NSMakeRange(0, currentString.length), with: newString)```, as the parameter must be ```(NSSting).length``` not ```(String).count```...

Comment: @tontonCD Nice detective work. Yes, when you're working in the NSString Cocoa world you need to stay in it. Swift will keep showing you NSStrings as Swift Strings, so you sometimes have to struggle a bit in order to stay in the NSString world.

Comment: Alternatively, don't call NSMakeRange. There is an NSRange initializer that lets you convert from a Swift string range to a Cocoa NSRange.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible to find ranges in `NSMutableAttributedString`.

Example :

```
let text = "[I love Ukraine!]"

var start = text.rangeOfString("[")
var finish = text.rangeOfString("]")

let mutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

let startIndex = mutableString.string.rangeOfString("[")
let finishIndex = mutableString.string.rangeOfString("]")
```

Example output from playground: [image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I found it. 
Windows end-of-line **"\r\n"** is two symbols in NSAttributedString but only one character in Swift String.
I use checking in my code:

```
let symbols = mutableString.string.characters.count
var extendedSymbols = 0
    while t < symbols {
        if str[t] == "\r\n" { extendedSymbols += 1 }
        else if str[t] == "[" {
            let startIndex = t + extendedSymbols
            while str[t] != "]" {
                t += 1
            }
            t += 1
            let endIndex = t + extendedSymbols

            mutableString.addAttribute(
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                value: UIColor.redColor(), 
                range: NSMakeRange(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex))
        }
        t += 1
    }
```

Thank you all for help!!!