# Range of all linkAttributed String in MutableAttributedString in swift

Tags: nsattributedstring

I have a mutableAttributedString in which few strings are linkAttributed,I want to find the Range of all link attributed string. How to do that in swift3 ?

When user start type @ in textview i show list of few name. If user select any row then following method gets called.

```
func didSelectMemberId(_ model: BaseModel) {

    var  fullName = ""
    if model.entityType == ReceiverType.Active.rawValue{
        fullName = model.name
    }else{
        fullName = AtMention + model.name + " " + model.name2
    }
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:fullName, attributes:[NSFontAttributeName:(appNeedsAutoResize ? (UIUtils.getFontForApproprieteField(.headlineWithoutBold).font) : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14))])

    attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "connectmention://\(model.entityId.stringValue())", range: NSRange(location: 0, length: fullName.length))

    attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: emptySpaceStringByUC, attributes:[NSFontAttributeName:(appNeedsAutoResize ? (UIUtils.getFontForApproprieteField(.headlineWithoutBold).font) : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14))]))


    self.composeBar.textView.textStorage.insert(attributedString, at:self.composeBar.textView.selectedRange.location)

 }
    self.composeBar.textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(self.composeBar.textView.selectedRange.location+fullName.length, 0 )
```

To get the link proprty I am using the following method

```
      func getlinkActionRange(attributeString: NSAttributedString) -> [MentionStruct] {
    var arrMentions = [MentionStruct]()
    _ =  attributeString.enumerateAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, in: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: attributeString.length), options: [], using: { (value, range, stop) in
        if let url = value {
            let occurrence = (attributeString.string as NSString).substring(with:range)
            arrMentions.append(MentionStruct(link: url as! String, text: occurrence, range: range))
        }
    })
    return arrMentions
}
```

If user type anything after inserting that name , that type string also coming.

Comment: `attr.enumerateAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, in: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: attr.length), options: [], using: { (value, range, stop) in let occurrence = (attr.string as NSString).substring(with:range); print("value: \(value)"); print("occurrence: \(occurrence)");})`?

Comment: Not working giving wrong range

Comment: I'm not a Swift developper, more Objective-C one, but could it be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832930/swift-string-count-vs-nsstring-length-not-equal ? How wrong are the ranges? Do you have a sample code?